# Sheets Query No Sort

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

Is there a way for a query to output unsorted? By default, it sorts the data.

I tried adding a helper column that adds the row number to the query input, but then it is not part of "select" like this:

```
=QUERY({Data!A1:C24,ArrayFormula(if(Data!A1:A24<>"",row(Data!A1:A24),""))},"Select Col1, Sum(Col2) group by Col1 pivot Col3 order by Col4")
```

Here is a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bMdCQKeWKqXI2Mmwpu__lHsGO2OttbJArWusBS8BMyQ/edit?usp=sharing

The desired output is that the query should show the points sum first for Apple, Orange, Banana etc.
[image: Screenshot of sample sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```
=sort(QUERY(Data!A1:C24,"Select A, Sum(B) group by A pivot C ",1),
match(query(A1:A24,"select min(A) group by A label min(A) 'Name'",1),A1:A24,0),1)
```

[image]

Or a bit shorter:

```
=sort(QUERY(Data!A1:C24,"Select A, Sum(B) group by A pivot C ",1),
match({A1;sortn(A2:A24,999,2)},A1:A24,0),1)
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain how this works? Is the match function just returning numbers in sequetial order? Why doesn't `=sort(QUERY(Data!A1:C24,"Select A, Sum(B) group by A pivot C ",1),
SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(Data!A1:A24)),1)` work?

Comment: You're trying to find which row the fruit name originally appeared in - so Apple, Banana,  Orange, Pear, Strawberry would give you 2,4,3,5,6 and you sort the rows of the pivot table (presented in alphabetical order) on that. Just using a sequence of numbers wouldn't reverse Banana and Orange.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(Data!A1:A), 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({Data!A1:C},
 "select Col1,sum(Col2)
  group by Col1
  pivot Col3")), 
 "order by Col1 desc", 1)), 
 {TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(UNIQUE(Data!C2:C))+1)))}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]